# Programmatically create and append a block to another block

Tags: magento2, blocks, custom-block

I've declared a plugin that creates and adds a block programmatically if a condition is true. However, my code outputs nothing, it's like if the created block is not rendered at all.

*etc/di.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AppendBlockPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

*Plugins/AddBlockPlugin.php*

```
public function beforeToHtml(AbstractBlock $block)
{
    if (($block instanceof Block\Product\View)
        && $block->getNameInLayout() === 'product.info'
    ) {
        $template = 'Vendor_Module::block.phtml';

        $block->addChild(
            'custom_block',
            \Vendor\Module\Block\Block::class,
            compact('template')
        );
    }
}
```

I've made some debugging to this code to ensue that the custom block renders without any errors and that the `->addChild` method is actually being called, but still no output for the block I added.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this by event.**

use event:

> layout_generate_blocks_after

**On this event add your block to `product.info`.**

### Event:

```
<?php
namespace [MyVendor]\[MyModule]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddAChildBlock implements ObserverInterface
{
    const TEMPLATE_TO_ADD = '[OtherVendor]_[OtherModule]::template.phtml';
    const PARENT_BlOCK_NAME = 'product.info';
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $blocks = $layout->getAllBlocks();
        foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
             $template = 'Vendor_Module::block.phtml';
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
            if ($block->getNameInLayout() == self:PARENT_BlOCK_NAME) {
                $blocks->addChild(
                'custom_block',
                 \Vendor\Module\Block\Block::class,
                    [
                        'template' => $template
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your parent template file means `product.info` you need to add the code

> echo  $block->getChildHtml('custom_block);

**to show the child block content**

Comment: That's still not showing any output of the custom block, although (again), I made sure that the `->addChild` method is being called.

Comment: I see that you have added the `echo` part to your answer. But, how can I achieve that while maintaining modularity?

Comment: If you parent block does not have  `$block->getChildHtml()` function then it is not easy to add the child block on   **render parent phtml** . Only possible to add child block on after html generetation of  parent template file .